# Trying to brute force roots for a hermite polynomial

Tags: c, math, runtime

I've got a program that is supposed to find the roots for the **th hermite polynomial by using Newton's method, but it's taking a long time to run the program. I'm pretty new to C, so I can't figure out where my bug is or if this is just the nature of brute forcing this problem. I'm also having issues getting accurate roots, but so far, it's hard to find that bug because I can only run a test case every 5-10 minutes

**CODE REMOVED**

Comment: 1/ **Never** use Newton for finding roots of polynomials. Use specific routines (eg. diagonalize the companion matrix). 2/ Roots of orthogonal polynomials are notoriously hard to compute inductively. The naive recursion relation in `hermite` is typically unstable. See Numerical Recipes for details (the section on Gaussian quadratures), one needs ~10 heavy pages to answer your question correctly. Also, the roots of Hermite polynomials have been tabulated for centuries, if you really need them (see eg. Abramowitz-Stegun)

Comment: Rescaling the recurrence relation by 2^n may help: http://www.haoli.org/nr/bookcpdf/c4-5.pdf (from the bottom of page 153)

Comment: @Alexandre C.: Newton's method should be fine for converging to the roots, *provided* you've got a good initial guess (in fact, the Numerical Recipes source that you point to does exactly this).  Getting the good initial guess is the sophisticated part.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Indeed. For orthogonal polynomials, you know that roots of H_n are between roots of H_{n-1}. However, except for orthogonal polynomials where you do have those guess, *in general*, Newton's method is almost impossible to get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 100% sure there's no good reason for Newton-Raphson to take so much time. In some cases it may be problematic, because this method isn't guaranteed to converge. But in your specific case - there should be no problem.

One thing that is clear is that you **monstrously** overuse recursion. Just calculating your `hermite` with n=37 is a recursion with complexity somewhat as summing 37 Fibonacci numbers, which is about **40 millions**.

Now, think that your `newton` method should invoke the `hermite` repeatedly, as well as `h_deriv` (which is of the same order of magnitude of recursion), up until in converges up to `10^-12`. Sounds like tens of interations.

And, not enough all this, you also manage to implement `newton` **recursively**! There is really no reason in the world to so this. (was lisp/scheme your first programming language?)

This is what you should do to improve the performance:

1. Fix your `hermite`. You should calculate the 37 **coefficients**, this may be done recursively. Once this is done - you should use them to calculate the the value of the polynomial in a normal time.
2. Same regarding the derivative. Just calculate the 36 coefficients.
3. Optionally fix your `newton`. As far as I can see - you'll not gain much of the performance: your "recursion" is an awkward loop nevertheless. However it'll look better, and consume much less stack.

**Edit**:

After reading the comments I took time and tried to build & run this. And, I must admit, I underestimated the problem complexity.

As turns out, the coefficients calculated by the recursive relation grow rapidly, and the round-off error seems to dominate. So that solving this problem by brute-force has unavoidable implications, and it's not obvious that using the pre-calculated coefficients (and summing them in the straight order) yields the same result.

Nevertheless there's a way to get rid of the ridiculous recursion without changing the calculation logic:

```
const int N = 37;

double g_pHermiteValues[N+1];

void CalcHermiteAt(double x)
{
    double x2 = x*2;

    g_pHermiteValues[0] = 1.;
    g_pHermiteValues[1] = x2;

    for (int n = 2; n <= N; n++)
        g_pHermiteValues[n] =
            g_pHermiteValues[n - 1] * x2 - 
            g_pHermiteValues[n - 2] * 2*(n - 1);
}

double CalcHermiteDerivAt()
{
    return g_pHermiteValues[N - 1] * 2*N;
}

double newton(double x_0)
{
    const double tolerance = 1E-12;

    while (true)
    {
        CalcHermiteAt(x_0);

        if (abs(g_pHermiteValues[N]) < tolerance)
            return x_0;

        x_0 -= g_pHermiteValues[N] / CalcHermiteDerivAt();
    }
}
```

That is, we use the same recursive relation. It's just in order to calculate the value of the Hermite polynomial at a given point we calculate it for all the polynomials up to n=37 **iteratively**, and store the results in the global array. Then its top element holds the needed result, and the derivative is also deduced from the 2nd array element from the end.

Since in Newton-Raphson algorithm at each step we need both the value and the derivative at the same point - this is done effectively.

P.S. However so far I could not come to the solution. The Newton-Raphson just doesn't converge for the points I've tried to start from.

I believe for such a question a more robust method may be used, such as a median search.

Comment: I put -1 because computing the coefficients is asking for trouble. They are monstruously large, and with alternating signs. Evaluating the polynomial incurs so much roundoff error that you get a nonsensical result. You ought to use induction for evaluation, but this also is not easy since the naive recursion scheme for orthogonal polynomials is typically unstable. This is *not* an easy problem (also Newton's method will typically fail here for other non obvious reasons).

Comment: Re 1 and 2:  not convinced by this---calculating the polynomials from the coefficients might be significantly more numerically unstable than calculating them from the recursion.  However, it should be possible to reuse already calculated values:  i.e., compute H_0(x) though to H_37(x) in a single loop, (the same way as you'd calculate the 37th Fibonacci number).

Comment: @Alexandre C: Alright, I agree that round-off errors may be a gotcha. However this is somewhat comparable to computing the function value directly.

Comment: @valdo: Try it. It is worth seeing it with your own eyes. Using the *proper* recurrence relation is the only way to go.

Comment: Rescaling the recurrence relation and having a good first guess for the Newton method works. This is not trivial to come up with (but the roots of Hermite polynomials have been tabulated for at least 200 years). See the link I posted as a comment to the question for details.